# TFS 2010 Workitem auto transition

Tags: tfs, workflow, workitem

How can I make work item to auto tansit from new to assigned state when I populate Assigned To field.
Ie. I have reported a bug so its state is new.
Now I populate (select from dropdown) the Assigned To field, and I want it to automatically transit to Assigned state (Active state).

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want cannot be done out of the box with TFS.

However, I created an open source project called [TFS Aggregator](http://tfsaggregator.codeplex.com/) to give the support you are looking for.

You could setup an aggregation something like this:

```
 <AggregatorItem operationType="String" linkType="Self" workItemType="Bug">
    <Mappings>      
      <Mapping targetValue="Assigned" inclusive="Or">
        <SourceValue>New</SourceValue>
      </Mapping>
    </Mappings>
    <Conditions>
      <Condition leftField="Assigned To" operator="NotEqualTo" rightValue=""/>
      <Condition leftField="State" operator="NotEqualTo" rightValue="Removed"/>
      <Condition leftField="State" operator="NotEqualTo" rightValue="Done"/>
      <Condition leftField="State" operator="NotEqualTo" rightValue="Ready For Test"/>
  <Condition leftField="State" operator="NotEqualTo" rightValue="In Progress"/>
    </Conditions>
    <TargetItem name="State"/>
    <SourceItem name="State"/>
  </AggregatorItem>
```

That should move your bug to Assigned from New.

Answer (score 0):

As already written this is not possible using TFS out-of-the-bos. But you can use [TFS ASAP](http://www.tfsasap.com/) to automate your work items. Further you can also aggregate numbers e.g. efforts and much more...